# Maybe weird behaviour of DOM tree updating (client side blazor, razor, C# .net ASP.net hosted)

Tags: dom, razor, tree, blazor, updating

Hello there,

i have just made a weird experience with the DOM tree updating of blazor.

The code is easy:

1) the user can choose between 2 Types A or B with radiobuttons.

2) when A or B is chosen, more options appear as checkboxes (A lets you select A1 and/or A2, B lets you select B1 and/or B2).

Big question is: what happens, if you do the following:

3) select A  (=> two checkboxes A1 and A2 appear)

4) check A1

5) select B  (=> A1 and A2 vanish, checkboxes B1 and B2 appear)

6) look at the state of B1

I made 2 different versions:

7) one, where i define the checkboxes for A and B separately   -> this works as intended (=B1 and B2 unchecked)

8) one, where i define them directly, but with the right name   -> this does not work! B1 is checked!

As i understand it, when selecting B (step 5), blazor updates the DOM tree. But i dont get why the browser remembers the checkbox B1 as checked, only because i checked A1, and even though i created it completely new. This looks like a bug to me. I mean, i even give the checkbox another name.

Is there a possibility to "clear the browser memory regarding the checking-state of the checkbox" or something else?

I created this minimum-example for simplicity. In my code, the checkboxes are created in a foreach, and i also have the not-intended behaviour.

Happy to hear your opinion and/or hints.
Tim

Here is the code of my razor component:

```
<!--  Define 2 Radio-Buttons, User selects A or B  -->
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="RB_Type" @onclick="@(() => SelectType("A"))" /> Type A
</label>
<br />
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="RB_Type" @onclick="@(() => SelectType("B"))" /> Type B
</label>
<br />

<!--  The following code works as intended  -->
@if (accType == "A")
{
    <input type="checkbox" name="A1" unchecked><label>A1</label>
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="A2" unchecked><label>A2</label>
    <br />
}
else if (accType == "B")
{
    <input type="checkbox" name="B1" unchecked><label>B1</label>
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="B2" unchecked><label>B2</label>
    <br />
}


<!--  The following code does not work as intended  -->
@if (accType != "")
{
    <input type="checkbox" name="@(accType + "1")" unchecked><label>@(accType + "1")</label>
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="@(accType + "2")" unchecked><label>@(accType + "2")</label>
    <br />
}




@code {

    private string accType = "";

    private void SelectType(string type)
    {
        this.accType = type;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add some `@key=""` attributes like so:

```
@if (accType != "")
{
    <input type="checkbox" @key="@(accType + "1")" name="@(accType + "1")" unchecked><label>@(accType + "1")</label>
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" @key="@(accType + "2")" name="@(accType + "2")" unchecked><label>@(accType + "2")</label>
    <br />
}
```

The blazor diff engine tries to minimize changes. So when it sees 2 checkboxes at the same place it will assume they *are* the same. The name property doesn't help to distinguish between A and B controls.

But you will find this 2nd version (`@(accType + "1")`) of your code is difficult in databinding too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

But it does not work, despite the fact, Visual Studio tells me when hovering above the "@key"
"Ensures that the component or element will be preserved across renders if (and only if) the supplied key value matches."

I am sure this is a bug.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, it works. Thanks! Now i try to figure out if databinding works fine. I wonder why the name attribute doesnt preserve across renders like the key attribute does. I mean, it is the name of the element, that should be uniquely defining.

Comment: No, `name` does not have to be unique (HTML rules). `id` should be but what if it isn't? No hard guarantees. Neither has to be present.